# Prove that a random variable $\tau \sim Geom(p)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb P)$ a discrete probability space, $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, $B\subset\Omega$ with $p:=\mathbb P_{X_1}(B)>0$.

$\tau: \Omega\to\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$, $\tau:=inf\{n\in\mathbb N: X_n\in B\}$

Prove that $$\tau \sim Geom(p)$$

Proof.

We have $$\mathbb P (\tau=k) = (1-P_{X_1}(B))*(1-P_{X_2}(B))...(1-P_{X_{k-1}}(B))*P_{X_k}(B)$$
Since $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d., $\mathbb P_{X_1}=...=\mathbb P_{X_n}$ und hence $\forall 1\le k \le n:$
$$\mathbb P (\tau=k) = (1-P_{X_1}(B))^{k-1}*P_{X_1}(B)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$$

Additionaly:
$$\mathbb P (\tau=\infty)=(\underbrace{1-p}_{<1})^{\infty}p=0$$
$\Rightarrow \tau \sim Geom(p)$

The part $\mathbb P (\tau=\infty)=(\underbrace{1-p}_{<1})^{\infty}p$ 
 doesn't look mathematically correct. Is the proof coherent and is it sufficient to just state $\mathbb P (\tau=\infty)=({1-p})^{\infty}p=0$? Could you otherwise tell me a correct way to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

From $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}P(\tau=k)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}(1-p)^{k-1}p=1$ it follows that $P(\tau=\infty)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(T=\infty)=P(T>n \forall n)=\lim_nP(T>n)=\lim_n (1-p)^n=0$

The second equality comes from the general properties of probability measures, according to which the probability of the intersection of a decreasing sequence of events equal the limit of the probabilities of such events.

Remark: a probability space where you can define such a sequence of iid variables is not a discrete probability space, but that is irrelant in the solution.